# Как вычислить дату?

Tags: sql

1. Есть порядковый номер изделия '009081029005357', в котором заложен месяц производства. Месяц вычисляется на основании 7, 8 и 9 цифры:

   ```
   declare @sn table(
       item [nvarchar](30) NULL)

   insert into @sn 
   SELECT substring([item],7,3)
     FROM [SLHistory].[dbo].[zip_op_def] with (nolock)
     where item between ('009081029005357') and ('009081047005357')
   ```

   Получаем табличку с уже вычисленными месяцами по системе: 029, 030, ..., 047.
2. Отчет месяцев в системе начался с 1-го октября 2008 года. Сейчас август 2011 и 047 месяц относительно 1-го октября 2008г.
3. Теперь на основании вычисленных месяцев по системе нужно определить, в каком году было выпущено изделие. Загвоздка в том, что год нужен не по системе, а по летоисчислению :)) Запуталась уже сильно. Помогите советом хотя бы! Работаю в среде Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

: Сейчас август 2011 и 047 месяц относительно 1-го октября 2008г.

47 - это почти 4 полных года, т.е. относительно 1-го октября 2008г получается 2012 год.

Comment: Месяц по системе точно 047, его вычисляет сама система и включает в порядковый номер изделия

Comment: Так обычно говорят бухгалтера. :-)
Значит точка отсчета другая. Легко же проверить:
select year(DATEADD(m,cast('047' as int),'20080928'))

Answer (score 4):

Использовать DATEADD

```
select YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, cast(substring(item, 7, 3) as int)-1, '1-10-2008')
from @sn
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот пример, как прибавить число прошедших месяцев и получить дату:

```
DECLARE  @myMonth INT
SET @myMonth = 029

-- прибавляем число месяцев к начальной дате
select DATEADD(mm, @myMonth, '2008-10-01')

-- получаем текущий год
select DATEPART(yy, DATEADD(mm, @myMonth, '2008-10-01'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну что тут можно посоветовать. Вычислять, если я правильно понял вопрос. Итак, есть порядковый номер месяца, начиная с октября 2008 года. Делите с остатком - получаете количество лет, которое надо приплюсовать к 2008. Остаток - месяц по порядку в этом году минус 3 (потому что отсчет с октября). 
Например. 
47/12 = 3 года и 11 месяцев. Таким образом год 2011 (2008 + 3) и месяц 8 ( = 11 - 3).

Как разделить с остатком в SQL Server - не знаю. Можно написать свои арифметические процедуры, это несложно.

Comment: Спасибо! Придется подумать как делить с остатком! ;)

Comment: Не надо :) Там ниже уже советуют более правильное решение. Я не знал про DATEADD. Лучше использовать его, раз оно есть. В тех базах, с которыми работаю я, их нет.

Comment: Деление по модулю в T-SQL не отличается оригинальностью. Это оператор %

Answer (score 1):

А если вот так попробовать?

```
declare @SN nvarchar (30) 
, @Date datetime 
, @Date2 datetime

set @Date = '01.09.2007' 
set @SN = '007791047006455'

set @date2 = dateadd(m,cast(SUBSTRING(@SN,7,3) as int),dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,@Date),0))

select 
@date2 [Дата] 
,MONTH(@date2) [Месяц] 
,DATENAME (m ,@date2) [Месяц_Имя] 
,YEAR (@date2) [Год] 
,DATENAME (yyyy ,@date2)+' г.' [Год_Имя]
![alt text][1]
```

Вот что получается! Как раз то, что мне нужно!

Comment: Тоже хороший вариант. Могу добавить, что я задаю даты как yyyy-mm-dd, ибо запись dd.mm.yyyy не всегда правильно воспринимается серверами, т.к. у американов месяц на первом месте: mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Останется сделать привязку к базе и, думаю, должно получиться!Спасибо всем огромное!!!

Comment: Плохой вариант. в чем смылс выражения dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,@Date),0) которое тождественно равно @Date? занять делом сервер?

Comment: Если дата задается строковым литералом, то формат литерала определяется а) языком, с которым соединяется клиент. бэ) вызовом SET DATEFORMAT или SET LANGUAGE. Не уверены в сервере - вызовите явно SET DATEFORMAT dmy

Comment: Вставила картинку с результатом, но почему-то не видно ее.